# Mysql subquery field unknown

Tags: mysql

I have read many posts have a solution for this but this does not work in my case. What am I doing wrong? 
- This gives me the SUM of scores for every user and this is the first part.( Aggregated Data)
[The Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTBQQ.png)

```
SELECT user_id, sum(score) as total_user_score
FROM (
   SELECT comments_proper.user_id, comments_proper.score
   FROM assignment_2.comments_proper
) AS rsch 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

However, I want only 2 records which contain the min and the max score values.

Comment: Your subquery beginning `SELECT MIN(total_user_score)` doesn't have a FROM clause. And, your parentheses in your query are not balanced.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You've mixed half a dozen different layouts for your query.  Pick one and stick to it and you might be able to spot syntactic errors in your code more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Oh dear, where to begin.

> I have read many posts

You should have been paying attention to which ones got up-voted and good answers, and which were down-voted/closed. The former would have included the table structures, examples of input and expected output. And unambiguous questions.

> I want only 2 records

Is that from the source data set or from the aggregated data set?

The latter is a slightly tricky problem which has been asked and answered many times here on SO, there are multiple solutions with different performance characteristics. There's even a [chapter in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) covering just this question. The current content at that link uses subqueries to identify the min/max value which replaces an earlier version of the documentation which explained [the max-concat trick](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.305.1/finding_values_associated_with_minimum_and_maximum_values.html), but its also possible to use variables to identify the right caddidate rows in a sub-query or to use sorting.

However the SQL you've shown us here, has very little to do with solving the problem you describe, and is **very** badly written.

I won't provide examples of every solution, but this will solve your problem...

```
 SELECT user_id, SUM(score)
 FROM assignment_2.comments_proper
 GROUP BY user_id
 ORDER BY SUM(score) 
 UNION 
 SELECT user_id, SUM(score)
 FROM assignment_2.comments_proper
 GROUP BY user_id
 ORDER BY SUM(score)
```

**updated**
I hadn't tested the above. I did test this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(score)
  FROM assignment_2.comments_proper
  GROUP BY user_id
  ORDER BY SUM(score)  LIMIT 0,1
) as lowest
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(score)
  FROM assignment_2.comments_proper
  GROUP BY user_id
  ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC LIMIT 0,1
 ) as highest
```

Comment: thanks. I thought my question is very simple and common. In the image I have posted. it clear that it is aggregated data not a source. Now from the result I have in the pic. I want to have only the the highest and lowest scored comments. Your query gives `incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER By` [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTBQQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your queries you have some problem of sintax and a too complex calculation for aggregated  resul anyway .. in cp1.* result you have the min related  values in cp2.* the max related.

If you need  all the resuly for min  and max rows on the same row you can use a couple of inner join  based on the aggregated  result

```
select cp1.* , cp2.*
from ( SELECT  cp.user_id, sum(cp.score), min(cp.score) min_score, max(cp.score) max_score
              FROM assignment_2.comments_proper cp
              group by cp.user_id ) t 
inner join assignment_2.comments_proper cp1 on cp1.user_id = t.user_id 
            and cp1.score = t.min_score
inner join assignment_2.comments_proper cp2 on cp2.user_id = t.user_id 
          and cp2.score = t.max_score
```

otherwise if you want the result in two rows one for min and one for max

```
  select 'min' , cp1.*
  from (  SELECT  cp.user_id, sum(cp.score), min(cp.score) min_score, max(cp.score) max_score
              FROM assignment_2.comments_proper cp
            group by cp.user_id ) t 
  inner join assignment_2.comments_proper cp1 on cp1.user_id = t.user_id 
            and cp1.score = t.min_score
  union 

  select 'max' , cp2.*
  from (  SELECT  cp.user_id, sum(cp.score), min(cp.score) min_score, max(cp.score) max_score
              FROM assignment_2.comments_proper cp
            group by cp.user_id ) t 
  inner join assignment_2.comments_proper cp2 on cp2.user_id = t.user_id 
          and cp2.score = t.max_score
```

Comment: I have updated the question, would you re-form your answer ?

Comment: answer  updated  .. hope this is what you are looking for